# Cant align printf code correctly

Tags: c, styles, alignment, printf

When I try to print pretty in C I can't seem to make it align correctly. I've tried for a long time now and haven't been able to find any help online.
Could someone explain me why this doesn't work and what I should do instead?

I wish to align them correctly..
[This is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Haszz.png)

```
printf("%-20s%s %-22s%-12d"
   "%-12s%-12s%-12s%-12s\n",
   cyclist[i]->race_name, cyclist[i]->first_name, cyclist[i]->last_name, cyclist[i]->age,
   cyclist[i]->team, cyclist[i]->nation, cyclist[i]->placement, cyclist[i]->race_time);
```

Header print

```
void print_header(){
printf("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
printf("%-20s%-27s%-12s%-12s%-12s%-12s%-12s\n", "RACE NAME", "FULDE NAVN", "ALDER", "HOLD", "NATION", "PLADS", "TID");
printf("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
```

}

Comment: I found out it has something to do with the fact that I have both an first_name and last_name... removing one of them makes the list aligned but cant seem to make it work with both being there.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make one string using first and last name.

Do like this :

```
printf("%-20s%-27s%-12d"
   "%-12s%-12s%-12s%-12s\n",
   "race_name", "first_name last_name", 25,
   "team", "nation", "placement", "race_time");
```

Answer (score 0):

You print `"FULDE NAVN"` as `"%-27s"` for the header. But print the first and last names as `"%s %-22s"`. Those formats are not the same, and will have problems if the first name is longer than 4 characters.

I suggest you for the full-name column create a temporary string for the names, and print it as a single string.

Perhaps something like

```
char full_name[28];
snprintf(full_name, sizeof(full_name), "%s %s",
    cyclist[i]->first_name, cyclist[i]->last_name);

printf("%-20s%-27s%-12d%-12s%-12s%-12s%-12s\n",
    cyclist[i]->race_name, full_name, cyclist[i]->age, ...);
```

Now the formats for both the header and data printouts will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

The second `%s` has no number inside it

```
printf("%-20s%s %-22s%-12d"
   "%-12s%-12s%-12s%-12s\n",
```

should be changed to

```
printf("%-20s%10s %-22s%-12d"
   "%-12s%-12s%-12s%-12s\n",
```

Then of course, the rest of the header will need to be lined up.

My suggestions are to a) save the formatStr to a variable to the same one is used for the header as the rows, and b) format the names into their own string `sprintf(full_name, "%s %s", first_name, last_name)`